# SSRS Report Timing out in Production Server (except after refreshing 3 times)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The report works fine in the DEV and QA server but when placed in Production the following error comes up:

```
An error occurred during client rendering. 
An error has occurred during report processing. 
Query execution failed for dataset 'Registration_of_Entity'. 
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

The strange part was that the Admins have assured me that this report has now been set so there is no timeout at all.

Refresh the report 3 times every morning and the error message goes away.

What can I do to fix this issue so that the report never receives this error?

Comment: Can you have the DBA's monitor server activity when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps to resolve correctly this issue.
I advise following them in the following order:

---

**1. Reduce the query execution time**
Execute the query of the DataSet `Registration_of_Entity` in SSMS and see how long it takes to complete.
If your query requires more time to execute than the timeout specified for the DataSet, you should first try to reduce this time, for example:

- Change the query structure (rethink joins, use CTEs, ...)
- Add indexes

Looking at the execution plan can help.

---

**2. Reduce the query complexity**

Do you need all those rows/columns?
Do you need to have all these calculations on the database side?
Could it be done in the report instead?
You could try to:

- Reduce the query complexity
- Split the query in smaller queries

Again, looking at the execution plan can help.

---

**3. Explore additional optimizations not related to the query itself**
You really need this query, but do you need the data real-time?
Are there a lot of other queries being executed on this server?
You could look into:

- Caching
- Replication / Load Balancing

> Note that from SSRS 2008 R2, the new Shared DataSets can be cached. I
>   know it doesn't apply in your case but who knows, it could help
>   others.

---

**4. Last resort**
If all the above steps failed to solve the issue, then you can increase the timeouts.
[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ssrs/archive/2009/10/30/steps-to-resolve-ssrs-timeout-issues.aspx) is a link to a blog post explaining the different timeouts and how to increase them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if your query is becoming deadlocked? It could be that the report gets blocked on the server during peak times.

Consider optimizing your query or, if the data can be read uncommitted, add WITH (NOLOCK) after each FROM and Join Clause. Be sure to google WITH(NOLOCK) if you are unfamiliar with it so you know what read uncommitted can do.